# UIView animateWithDuration shows error

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I have successfully implemented UIView animateWithDuration in Objective-c but when I try to implement it in Swift it not working and give error as 
**Cannot invoke animateWithDuration with an argument list of type**

My Objective-C code is:

```
self.bottomConstraint.constant = 0;
    [self.picker setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
```

I want to convert same code in swift. How can I convert?

Comment: can you show your tried swift code

Comment: Edit your question to show the Swift code that is giving you problems or this question will be closed. 'Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```

Swift `5`:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) { () -> Void in
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    return
}
```

**Key here is** : Animation closure is supposed to return `Void` so explicit `return` should resolve your issue.